# Windows Azure MessageLockLostException

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm having issues with Azure Message Bus Queues.

I'm having `MessageLockLostException` thrown and *The request operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:10. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout*.

I've set my queue into `ReceiveMode.PeekLock`.

I also check

```
if(message.LockedUntilUtc.Minute <= 1)
    message.RenewLock();
```

Why would this happen, what's causing the lock to give out? I was reading somewhere from the point where you Receive you have 5 minutes by default. This process takes a little longer usually. I wanted to renew the lock but this isn't working too well.

Comment: Is it me or does your message not tell you your lock timeout is 1:10 (70 seconds)?  That configuration is set when the queue is created.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [LockDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.lockduration.aspx) is property of the Queue. You typically set this when you create the Queue. This is `Queue` level property and cannot be changed on a message base. What you've read, most probably is saying that this duration cannot be longer than 5 minutes. The default value is 1 Minute, that's why you face issues. And why you face it 70 seconds later - I assume the logic for checking this conditions is executed every 10 seconds.

So I suggest that you create or modify your Queue to set [LockDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.lockduration.aspx) property to 5 minutes. Then, while working [RenewLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.renewlock.aspx) of your message when appropriate.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That makes more sense!

For additional information: QueueDescription is where LockDuration exists.

Comment: As a side note, the default value when you create a queue from the management portal is 30 seconds.

Comment: As a side note for people seeing this type error working with topics. There's a lock duration on the subscriber level which fixes.