# Mark Azure Queue BrokeredMessage as Processed successfully?

Tags: c#, azure

I receive queue message in worker role, but when I try to mark `BrokeredMessage` as complete. I get below error:

```
Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
    {
        try
        {
            FileContainer fileInfoObj = receivedMessage.GetBody<FileContainer>();               
            //Message processing code               

            receivedMessage.Complete();                           

        }
        catch
        {
            receivedMessage.DeadLetter();
        }
    });
```

> The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message
>   has already been removed from the queue.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How long is "Message processing code" taking? There is an expiration time for the lock. The default timeout is 1 minute. Use `QueueDescription.LockDuration` to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Mike Z's comment, set the [LockDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.lockduration.aspx) (default is 1, can be up to 5 mins) when you create the queue to prevent timeout.

```
QueueDescription qd = new QueueDescription("MyQueue");
qd.LockDuration = ...

if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists("MyQueue"))
{
    namespaceManager.CreateQueue(qd);
}
```

Also, use [RenewLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.renewlock.aspx) to prevent it from timing out during a long process:

```
receivedMessage.RenewLock()
```

From here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305150/188926